# Disable POIs in Google Maps iframe with HTML

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe

We are integrating Google Maps with an iframe.
Unfortunately the map is displaying POIs by the competitors. Is there any possibility to disable them with a suffix in the HTML?

http://www.sorba.ch/kontakt

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d10798.188248369914!2d9.3721622!3d47.4207752!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x1721878daf7af98e!2sSorba+EDV+AG!5e0!3m2!1sde!2sch!4v1507043605585" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

Or is it just possible with JavaScript?

Comment: This is only possible with the Google Maps JavaScript API v3.

Comment: You can also modify the map tiles with a Static Map to remove the POIs, but that won't be dynamic, and you would have to put the "Place Information" on it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do this with HTML; HTML sets the initial structure of your application, it does not change its behaviour. If you need to change the behaviour or style the response returned from the Google servers, you can indeed use the Javascript API. You can indeed [style your map to filter out businesses](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) by setting their respective visibility to “off”. This is a quick sample you could model to achieve this:

```
function initialiseMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {

      // center the map to your business address
      // Set a marker with an InfoWindow if you like to model map in the example

      center: {lat: xx.xxxxx, lng: yy.yyyy},
      zoom: zz,
      styles: [
          {
          featureType: “poi.business”,
          elementType: “labels”,
          stylers: [{visibility: “off”}]
          }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Do you know any example here at stackoverflow how to integrate the javascript of maps or where to call it in HTML? Or any tutorial for dummies how to use Google Maps with Javascript customization in HTML?

Comment: If you check the link provided in my answer, that gives you an excellent starting point to specifically address your issue. More broadly, within that documentation (Google Maps JavaScript API),  you can also find clear examples that will get you started in no times. If my answer was useful to you, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for comments and help.
I switched to a JavaScript designed map. Difficult but the right direction.

Who also needs some help or introduction should visit:

https://mapkit.io/ (I am generating the base code with this great tool)

and

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/?hl=de